# IntelliJ mappings not in IdeaVims insert mode

Tags: intellij-idea, ideavim

I am using IntelliJ with the IdeaVim plugin. I want to map L/H to switch to next/prev tab. If I configure it in the IntelliJ settings (Settings->Keymap) the binding is also active when I am in insert mode of IdeaVim, which means I cannot type a uppercase l or h. I have tried both the "Editor Action" as well as the Plugins->IdeaVim action.

I guess I could solve it by specifying the mapping in `~/.ideavimrc`, but I don't find the right command for switching tabs, because IdeaVim does not seem to offer any of the commands I know from vim (`bn`, `bnext`, `tabn`, ..)

Thanks!

Comment: Mapping "normal" characters can be problematic in intellij. Can you map them to `alt` or `ctrl` L/H instead?

Comment: Yeah.. I could use another mapping, but I would really like to use `L` and `H`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IdeaVim uses `gt` and `gT` for switching tabs. Remap any keys to them using `:map`-family commands in your ~/.ideavimrc, e.g.:

```
map <C-Up> gT
imap <C-Up> <C-O>gT
map <C-Down> gt
imap <C-Down> <C-O>gt
```

Comment: Using this I got it working. I previously defined the mappings using IntelliJ's settings editor. When I put this in my `.ideavimrc` everything works flawlessly!
`map H gT` and `map L gt` respectively.